# MySQL Complex Insert With Conditional Subselect?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

so I'm having trouble properly creating this query.

Basically, I want to insert multiple rows into the notification table, each row being inserted having a unique recipient id that will not be duplicate, the recipient id's are determined by checking for a matching target_id of a comment, or id of a stream and checking the author_id's associated with each comment / stream. Also, I want the query to exclude row insertion for author_id's selected that match the sender id.

Below is a rough sql markup of basically what I need.

```
INSERT INTO
notification (type,
target_id,
sender_id,
recipient_id,
data,
timestamp,
is_unread)
SELECT DISTINCT 'comment', 
'$id',
'$senderId',
(comment.author_id OR stream.author_id), 
'$dataArray',
'$timestamp', 
'1'
FROM 
    stream,
    comment
WHERE 
    stream.author_id != '$senderId'
    AND comment.author_id != '$senderId'
    AND stream.id = '$id'
    OR comment.target_id = '$id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have seems fine.  You can try using `COALESCE(stream.author_id, comment.author_id)` so if the comment author_id is null (e.g. because the author_id is the sender) it will fall back on the stream's author_id.  For this to work, you have to outer join comment on stream, and the `stream.author_id != '$senderId'` condition has to be part of the `ON` clause.

Comment: How would the query be structured then? I have no experience using Coalesce

Comment: It's just `COALESCE(field1, field2)`